# Selenium: How to get td objects within tr objects

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get rows of information for a user using Selenium and xpaths. I am able to get the rows using the following code:

```
String xpath = "//tbody[contains(@class,'svelte-abc')]//tr";
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
```

What I am not sure is how to then parse the individual elements (TD's) for the row, e.g. the first one is a name, the second is email address.

The html is:

```
<table class="svelte-abc">
    <thead>
    .....
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="svelte-abc">
            <td class="def">
                <div class="ace">
                    <img ... >
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="def">A Person</td>
            <td class="def">email@address.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired information is distributed among several *`<td>`s*. So you have to identify the specific *`<td>`s*

To parse the texts you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Printing *A Person*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='svelte-abc']//tbody/tr[@class='svelte-abc']//following::td[2]")).getText());
  ```
- Printing *email@address.com*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='svelte-abc']//tbody/tr[@class='svelte-abc']//following::td[3]")).getText());
  ```

Comment: This returns all of the users information as individual TD's, when you have multiple users this doesn't feel tidy.  Is there a way to get a row and then findelement within that row?